# Improve PostgreSQL query performance having left join for 100 millions of data

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I am using `Postgresql-9.2 version`, `Windows 7 64 bit`, `RAM 6GB`. This is a Java enterprise project.

I have to show orders related info in my page. There are three tables which are brought together via a left join.

**Tables:**

1. TV_HD (389772 rows)
2. TV_SNAPSHOT (1564756 rows)
3. TD_MAKKA (419298 rows)

After left joining 3 tables, the query gives `487252`. It will also increase day by day.

[image]

Table Relationship:

1. TV_HD contains "one to many" relationship with TV_SNAPSHOT
2. TV_HD contains "one to many" relationship with TD_MAKKA

For better understanding I am now giving a pictorial view with sql query

**SELECT * FROM tv_hd where urino = 1630799**
[image]

**SELECT * FROM tv_snapshot where urino = 1630799**
[image]

**SELECT * FROM td_makka where urino = 1630799**
[image]
This query runs in approximately 90 seconds.  How can I improve my query performance?

I have also thought about indexing. But as far I know, indexing is actually used when we want to get 2%-4% data from table.` But in my case, I need all of data from those 3 tables.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM (SELECT HD.URINO
      FROM
        TV_HD HD
        LEFT JOIN TV_SNAPSHOT T ON (HD.URINO = T.URINO AND HD.TCODE = T.TCODE AND T.DELFLG = 0 AND T.SYUBETSU = 1)
        LEFT JOIN TV_SNAPSHOT T_SQ
          ON (HD.URINO = T_SQ.URINO AND HD.SQCODE = T_SQ.TCODE AND T_SQ.DELFLG = 0 AND T_SQ.SYUBETSU = 3)
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT N.URINO
                   FROM
                     TD_MAKKA N
                   WHERE
                     N.UPDATETIME IN (
                       SELECT MIN(NMIN.UPDATETIME)
                       FROM
                         TD_MAKKA NMIN
                       WHERE
                         N.URINO = NMIN.URINO
                         AND
                         NMIN.TORIKESHIFLG <> -1
                     )
                  ) NYUMIN
          ON (HD.URINO = NYUMIN.URINO)
        LEFT JOIN
        (
          SELECT
            NSUM.URINO,
            SUM(COALESCE(NSUM.NYUKIN, 0))                                                             NYUKIN,
            SUM(COALESCE(NSUM.NYUKIN, 0)) + SUM(COALESCE(NSUM.TESU, 0)) + SUM(COALESCE(NSUM.SOTA, 0)) SUMNYUKIN
          FROM
            TD_MAKKA NSUM
          GROUP BY
            URINO
        ) NYUSUM
          ON (HD.URINO = NYUSUM.URINO)
        LEFT JOIN
        (
          SELECT N.URINO
          FROM
            TD_MAKKA N
          WHERE
            UPDATETIME = (
              SELECT MAX(UPDATETIME)
              FROM
                TD_MAKKA NMAX
              WHERE
                N.URINO = NMAX.URINO
                AND
                NMAX.TORIKESHIFLG <> -1
            )
        ) NYUMAX
          ON (HD.URINO = NYUMAX.URINO)
      WHERE ((HD.URIBRUI <> '1') OR (HD.URIBRUI = '1' AND T_SQ.NYUKOBEFLG = '-1'))
      ORDER BY
        HD.URINO DESC
     ) COUNT_
```

Here is the result of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`

```
Aggregate  (cost=7246861.21..7246861.22 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=69549.159..69549.159 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=7240188.92..7242117.36 rows=379508 width=6) (actual time=68602.689..69510.563 rows=487252 loops=1)
        Merge Cond: (hd.urino = n.urino)
        ->  Sort  (cost=3727299.33..3728248.10 rows=379508 width=6) (actual time=62160.072..62557.132 rows=420036 loops=1)
              Sort Key: hd.urino
              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 6984kB
              ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=169264.26..3686940.26 rows=379508 width=6) (actual time=54796.930..60172.248 rows=420036 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (n.urino = hd.urino)
                    ->  Seq Scan on td_makka n  (cost=0.00..3511201.36 rows=209673 width=6) (actual time=24.326..4640.020 rows=419143 loops=1)
                          Filter: (SubPlan 1)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 155
                          SubPlan 1
                            ->  Aggregate  (cost=8.33..8.34 rows=1 width=23) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=419298)
                                  ->  Index Scan using idx_td_makka on td_makka nmin  (cost=0.00..8.33 rows=1 width=23) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=1 loops=419298)
                                        Index Cond: (n.urino = urino)
                                        Filter: (torikeshiflg <> (-1)::numeric)
                                        Rows Removed by Filter: 0
                    ->  Hash  (cost=163037.41..163037.41 rows=379508 width=6) (actual time=54771.078..54771.078 rows=386428 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 4096  Batches: 16  Memory Usage: 737kB
                          ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=75799.55..163037.41 rows=379508 width=6) (actual time=51599.167..54605.901 rows=386428 loops=1)
                                Hash Cond: ((t_sq.urino = hd.urino) AND (t_sq.tcode = hd.sqcode))
                                Filter: ((hd.uribrui <> '1'::bpchar) OR ((hd.uribrui = '1'::bpchar) AND (t_sq.nyukobeflg = (-1)::numeric)))
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 3344
                                ->  Seq Scan on tv_snapshot t_sq  (cost=0.00..73705.42 rows=385577 width=15) (actual time=0.053..2002.953 rows=389983 loops=1)
                                      Filter: ((delflg = 0::numeric) AND (syubetsu = 3::numeric))
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 1174773
                                ->  Hash  (cost=68048.99..68048.99 rows=389771 width=14) (actual time=51596.055..51596.055 rows=389772 loops=1)
                                      Buckets: 4096  Batches: 16  Memory Usage: 960kB
                                      ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=21125.85..68048.99 rows=389771 width=14) (actual time=579.405..51348.270 rows=389772 loops=1)
                                            Hash Cond: (nyusum.urino = hd.urino)
                                            ->  Subquery Scan on nyusum  (cost=0.00..35839.52 rows=365638 width=6) (actual time=17.435..49996.674 rows=385537 loops=1)
                                                  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.00..32183.14 rows=365638 width=34) (actual time=17.430..49871.702 rows=385537 loops=1)
                                                        ->  Index Scan using idx_td_makka on td_makka nsum  (cost=0.00..21456.76 rows=419345 width=34) (actual time=0.017..48357.702 rows=419298 loops=1)
                                            ->  Hash  (cost=13969.71..13969.71 rows=389771 width=20) (actual time=491.549..491.549 rows=389772 loops=1)
                                                  Buckets: 4096  Batches: 32  Memory Usage: 567kB
                                                  ->  Seq Scan on tv_hd hd  (cost=0.00..13969.71 rows=389771 width=20) (actual time=0.052..242.415 rows=389772 loops=1)
        ->  Sort  (cost=3512889.60..3512894.84 rows=2097 width=6) (actual time=6442.600..6541.728 rows=486359 loops=1)
              Sort Key: n.urino
              Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 8600kB
              ->  Seq Scan on td_makka n  (cost=0.00..3512773.90 rows=2097 width=6) (actual time=0.135..4053.116 rows=419143 loops=1)
                    Filter: ((updatetime)::text = (SubPlan 2))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 155
                    SubPlan 2
                      ->  Aggregate  (cost=8.33..8.34 rows=1 width=23) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=419298)
                            ->  Index Scan using idx_td_makka on td_makka nmax  (cost=0.00..8.33 rows=1 width=23) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=1 loops=419298)
                                  Index Cond: (n.urino = urino)
                                  Filter: (torikeshiflg <> (-1)::numeric)
                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 0
Total runtime: 69575.139 ms
```

Here is the explain analyze result details:

http://explain.depesz.com/s/23Fg

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions + remove all the clutter from the query, you don't need all those columns if all you're doing is a count. Fix formatting. Also please note that index are also used for joins, especially since you're only doing a count here instead of selecting all the values.

Comment: Let's start here:  `EXPLAIN ANALYZE <long_query_here>`.  Let us know what the analysis comes back as and then we can talk about optimizing it.  It's tough to say *what* needs fixing if that's unclear.

Comment: @Makoto I have added "explain analyze" info and updated query. Please check and give me some suggestion to quell

Comment: It'd help a little more if you also told us how these tables relate.  From what I'm seeing right now, those sequential scans are *killing* your performance; this implies that at the bare minimum, the `urino` column would benefit from indexing.

Comment: @Makoto I have added table details with image. Please check.

Comment: The info you added doesn't tell us how these tables relate; why joining on those columns makes sense.

Comment: @Makoto I have added table relationship. Please check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First step:
You could remove more column which is not required in your select query where as you only need to count the total rows. For Example:

```
select count(*) from ( SELECT
    HD.URINO
FROM
    TV_HD HD
    LEFT JOIN TV_SNAPSHOT T ON (HD.URINO = T.URINO AND HD.TCODE = T.TCODE AND T.DELFLG = 0 AND T.SYUBETSU = 1)
    LEFT JOIN TV_SNAPSHOT T_SQ ON (HD.URINO = T_SQ.URINO AND HD.SQCODE = T_SQ.TCODE AND T_SQ.DELFLG = 0 AND T_SQ.SYUBETSU = 3)
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT
                    N.URINO
            FROM
                TD_MAKKA N
            WHERE
                N.UPDATETIME IN (
                    SELECT
                        MIN (NMIN.UPDATETIME)
                    FROM
                        TD_MAKKA NMIN
                    WHERE
                        N.URINO = NMIN.URINO
                    AND
                        NMIN.TORIKESHIFLG <> -1 
                )
        ) NYUMIN
    ON  (HD.URINO = NYUMIN.URINO) 
            LEFT JOIN
                (
                    SELECT
                        NSUM.URINO
                        ,SUM (COALESCE(NSUM.NYUKIN ,0)) NYUKIN
                        ,SUM (COALESCE(NSUM.NYUKIN ,0)) + SUM (COALESCE(NSUM.TESU ,0)) + SUM (COALESCE(NSUM.SOTA ,0)) SUMNYUKIN
                    FROM
                        TD_MAKKA NSUM
                    GROUP BY
                        URINO
                ) NYUSUM
            ON  (HD.URINO = NYUSUM.URINO)
            LEFT JOIN
                (
                    SELECT
                         N.URINO
                    FROM
                        TD_MAKKA N
                    WHERE
                        UPDATETIME = (
                            SELECT
                                MAX (UPDATETIME)
                            FROM
                                TD_MAKKA NMAX
                            WHERE
                                N.URINO = NMAX.URINO
                            AND
                                NMAX.TORIKESHIFLG <> -1 
                        )
               ) NYUMAX
            ON  (HD.URINO = NYUMAX.URINO)
WHERE ( (HD.URIBRUI <> '1') OR ( HD.URIBRUI = '1' AND T_SQ.NYUKOBEFLG = '-1' ) )
 ORDER BY 
 HD.URINO DESC
  ) COUNT_
```

Second Step:
You could avoid left join which does not have significance for getting the row counts.
For Example:

```
select count(*) from ( SELECT
    HD.URINO
FROM
    TV_HD HD
    LEFT JOIN TV_SNAPSHOT T ON (HD.URINO = T.URINO AND HD.TCODE = T.TCODE AND T.DELFLG = 0 AND T.SYUBETSU = 1)
    LEFT JOIN TV_SNAPSHOT T_SQ ON (HD.URINO = T_SQ.URINO AND HD.SQCODE = T_SQ.TCODE AND T_SQ.DELFLG = 0 AND T_SQ.SYUBETSU = 3)
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT
                    N.URINO
            FROM
                TD_MAKKA N
            WHERE
                N.UPDATETIME IN (
                    SELECT
                        MIN (NMIN.UPDATETIME)
                    FROM
                        TD_MAKKA NMIN
                    WHERE
                        N.URINO = NMIN.URINO
                    AND
                        NMIN.TORIKESHIFLG <> -1 
                )
        ) NYUMIN
    ON  (HD.URINO = NYUMIN.URINO) 
            LEFT JOIN
                (
                    SELECT
                         N.URINO
                    FROM
                        TD_MAKKA N
                    WHERE
                        UPDATETIME = (
                            SELECT
                                MAX (UPDATETIME)
                            FROM
                                TD_MAKKA NMAX
                            WHERE
                                N.URINO = NMAX.URINO
                            AND
                                NMAX.TORIKESHIFLG <> -1 
                        )
               ) NYUMAX
            ON  (HD.URINO = NYUMAX.URINO)
WHERE ( (HD.URIBRUI <> '1') OR ( HD.URIBRUI = '1' AND T_SQ.NYUKOBEFLG = '-1' ) )

  ) COUNT_
```

Third Step: You could use **PgAdmin Graphical Explain Plans** to analyze the query and avoid others unnecessary execution overhead.

Comment: It improves 50%-60% times. but I want it more comfortable. Could you please elaborate the second step more?

Answer (score 2):

**According to query:**

Here actual requirement is **count** all records which are found from inner sql.

**Optimization theory for counting all records:**

1. remove unnecessary field in SELECT query
2. remove ORDER BY ASC/DES portion(saves 7% - 10%)
3. remove aggregate functions(avg, sum, count etc)
4. Use standard VACCUUM to reclaim storage occupied by dead tuples.
5. Research the "**EXPLAIN ANALYZE [your_query_here]**" result from http://explain.depesz.com/

**Explanation No. 1:** remove unnecessary field in SELECT query

```
select count(*) from ( SELECT
    HD.URINO
    /*HD.URIBRUI,
    HD.TCODE,
    HD.SQCODE*/
FROM
    TV_HD HD)
```

**Explanation No. 2:** remove ORDER BY ASC/DES portion(saves 7% - 10%)

```
select count(*) from ( SELECT
    HD.URINO
FROM
    TV_HD HD
    /*ORDER BY HD.URINO DESC*/)
```

**Explanation No. 3:** remove aggregate functions(avg, sum, count etc)

```
select count(*) from ( SELECT
    name
    /*MAX(salary),
    AVG(salary)*/
FROM Emp)
```

**Explanation No. 4:** Use standard VACCUUM to reclaim storage occupied by dead tuples.

```
VACUUM (VERBOSE, ANALYZE) your_table;
```

In normal PostgreSQL operation, tuples that are deleted or obsoleted by an update are not physically removed from their table; they remain present until a VACUUM is done. Therefore it's necessary to do VACUUM `periodically`, `especially` on frequently-updated tables.

There are two variants of VACUUM: `standard VACUUM` and `VACUUM FULL`.

VACUUM FULL can reclaim more disk space but runs much more slowly. Also, the standard form of VACUUM can run in parallel with production database operations. (Commands such as SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE will continue to function normally, though you will not be able to modify the definition of a table with commands such as ALTER TABLE while it is being vacuumed.) VACUUM FULL requires exclusive lock on the table it is working on, and therefore cannot be done in parallel with other use of the table.

Generally, therefore, **administrators should strive to use `standard VACUUM` and `avoid VACUUM FULL`.**

For details:

1. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-vacuum.html
2. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/routine-vacuuming.html

Thanks for your time.